# Capitals after mdash

Tags: capitalization, colons, em-dashes

I would like to know if, in British English, if there is a question after emdash, do I need to start the question with a capital? for example

—Do you know what this means?

Also, what about a general sentence and not a question after the emdash?

I have the same question for a colon (but of course in not-so-formal writing colons are replaceable with emdashes).

thanks

Comment: (1) I've edited your question to remove the abbreviation e.g. which is at best terrible style choice before a dash. But you may wish to add say 'Here is my question' before the dash. **But** en-dashes are often used by writers in the UK where writers in the US would often consider only em-dashes correct. // (a) Lower-case letters are used after dashes in running script (except with 'I', proper nouns etc). (b) It is rare and getting rarer to follow a colon in running script with a capitalisation, but it is not unknown. (c) This is general reference, and has been covered before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [punctuation if dash introduces question sentences](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216298/punctuation-if-dash-introduces-question-sentences) //  [Should the first word after a colon be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/should-the-first-word-after-a-colon-be-capitalized)

Comment: Okay, I guess there should be no question that begins with capital after  mdash.Thanks for your answers.